How efficient is Coron's bivariate Coppersmith algorithm in practice?
The paper by Coron on bivariate coppersmith in https://iacr.org/archive/crypto2007/46220372/46220372.pdf states the complexity of the algorithm is $O(\log^{11}W)$ where $W$ usually is on order of the number to be factored.
How is this algorithm practical? Has anyone tried this algorithm for $1000$s of bits where the higher order bits of one of the factors is known? Does it run in much better than $O(\log^{11}W)$ bit operations in practical settings?

I didn't look at Solving Multivariate Coppersmith Problems with Known Moduli by Keegan Ryan yet, but maybe you'll find something useful in it. (I assume that you know Recovering cryptographic keys from partial information, by example by Gabrielle De Micheli and Nadia Heninger already.)
